# ¿Por qué "morcilla" es una frase improvisada por un actor?

Tags: etimología, significado

[**Morcilla**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PnBQhSF) tiene, además de las acepciones referidas a la carne, la de

> 3. f. coloq. En un espectáculo, palabra o frase improvisadas que añade un actor.

Esta acepción no parece tener ninguna relación con las demás.
¿De dónde viene esa acepción?

Comment: Primera aparición en el diccionario de la academia de 1869: "la añadidura de palabras ó cláusulas de su invencion que hacen los malos comediantes al papel que representan".

Answer (score 1):

No he podido encontrar textos que prueben la siguiente teoría, pero la expongo por si sirve de algo.

La expresión "que les den morcilla" es más antigua de lo que recoge la RAE. Aunque se incorporó al diccionario de la academia en 1984 con el significado

> expr. fig. y fam. que indica desprecio, mala voluntad hacia alguien, desinterés, etcétera

la expresión ya se venía usando desde mucho tiempo antes. La primera aparición que he encontrado ha sido en la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España, en el ejemplar de [La Discusión del 14 de junio de 1860](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0002233614&page=6&search=%22den%20morcilla%22&lang=es), en una letrilla de variedades que dice así:

> Ya en Rusia, ya en Austria,
>   ya en Las Dos-Sicilias,
>   el absolutismo
>   sufre mil tollinas.
>   Y si á nuestra tierra
>   viene con carlistas,
>   dice el pueblo entero:
>   «que les den morcilla.»

Ahora bien, nótese que la definición de "morcilla" al principio (en 1869, por la época de los versos mencionados) decía que eran añadiduras "que hacen los malos comediantes". No es descabellado pensar que el público, ante un artista semejante, pudiera pensar que este les estaba dando morcilla al no tenerles el respeto de aprenderse su papel de forma correcta, mostrando así su desinterés.

De ahí a calificar dichos añadidos como "morcillas" hay un paso.

Comment: [_Que te den morcilla_](http://www.yorokobu.es/que-te-den-morcilla/) viene de la costumbre de dar morcillas envenenadas a los perros callejeros, para matarlos. Se usó hasta finales del siglo XIX.

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado algo que puede tener algo que ver con el origen de ese uso de *morcilla*.

Hay un refrán que no conocía que dice:

> *La morcilla es lo único que se repite.*
>
> Dícese de todo aquello que no es fácil que vuelva a suceder o verificarse.

Fuente: https://archive.org/details/diccionarioderef01sbaruoft

Me aventuro a suponer que puede aplicarse esta expresión a las frases que dice un actor improvisando, ya que es difícil que las vuelva a repetir de la misma forma. Como lo que se repite es la morcilla debería ser el texto del guion lo que tuviera ese nombre, pero quién sabe si se acabó tomando solo la palabra *morcilla* como equivalente de toda la frase.